# Boot to Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS Recovery Mode not working

Tags: boot, grub2, data-recovery, mode

I am not able to boot into my Ubuntu today because the computer was powered off during update. Now I am trying to use recovery mode, but then I cannot access the recovery mode menu. After I choose the `Advanced Option` -> `Ubuntu, with Linux....(recovery mode)`, my screen is stuck as shown in the following screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Ubuntu 18?    Ubuntu desktop and server releases have a *yy.mm* format, and whilst specialist *snap* based releases like Ubuntu Core 18 for IoT appliances do use a *yy* format there are none titled just Ubuntu 18.  Please clarify your release as there is no Ubuntu 18.  (Server could mean the main Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Server release, or the specialist Ubuntu Core 18 which is intended for headless server systems, esp. in the cloud)   Have you tried an older kernel?   If by powered-off you mean turned off; I'd not try and boot it, but boot *live* media & `fsck` to check for *fs* errors & look there

Comment: I modified the Ubuntu version I have on my desktop. I have tried to use live media to run 'fsck', this command have cleared some errors but I still cannot boot the system or even the recovery mode.

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue if the kernel was updated, try booting into a kernel version at the bottom of the list that should be safe to use.